# Why mongodb not shown on my phpinfo?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed mongodb but somehow it is not showing on my phpinfo.

here are more details from my terminal:

```
~ $ which php
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php

~ $ php -v
PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2017 11:06:55) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

~ $ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

~ $ ls /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
mongodb.so   opcache.a    opcache.so   pdo_dblib.a  pdo_dblib.so pgsql.a      pgsql.so

~ $ mongo --version
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
```

I have also included `extension=mongodb.so` on my php.ini file

Any help is appreciated.